# Get a You Tube Player using Google Console key

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I am trying to add a You Tube video to my project.so,I got a key from **Google Console**.Then I got a  error occurred while initializing the You Tube player.

**Coding:**

```
 public class YoutubePlayActivity extends YouTubeFailureRecoveryActivity{
    public static final String DEVELOPER_KEY = "AIzaSy...";
    private String videoId;
    private YouTubePlayerView youTubeView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        super.onCreate(arg0);
        
        setContentView(R.layout.youtube_play);
        Bundle bundle= getIntent().getExtras();
        videoId= bundle.getString("videoid");
        
        FrameLayout frameLayout=(FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
        youTubeView = new YouTubePlayerView(this);
        frameLayout.addView(youTubeView);
        youTubeView.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
        
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.header_title)).setText(bundle.getString("title"));
        
        findViewById(R.id.blog_back).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
                
            }
        });
    }
    
    
    @Override
      public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
          boolean wasRestored) {
        if (!wasRestored) {
        try {
            if(videoId!=null){
                //2GPfZYwYZoQ
                player.cueVideo(videoId);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not a Valid Youtube Video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not a Valid Youtube Video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }   
          
        }
      }

      @Override
      protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
        return youTubeView;
      }

}
```

**Output:**

[image]

If I click the Get You Tube App.Then the Output seems like these:

[image]

**Logcat Error:**

Finally Logcat Error Occurred:

[image: logcat]

Then I try to change the key from Google Console.Again these kind of errors occurred.I have to get a You Tube App with the help of coding.That's why I am using a Google Console key.Anybody know how to solve these.Waiting for your reply.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check whether "YouTube" application is install on your device? If yes then just update it.And most of the time you tube application not working properly on emulator..

Comment: I didnt need to install.There is an another way to get the you tube application with the help of Google console key in our coding.Did you know that?

Comment: I had same problem that time I did this and its worked fine for  me...and  used You Tube APT for that...with Google console Key

Comment: Ok I will try and tell you later

Comment: I get a output by following your guidance. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
player.cueVideo(videoId);
```

to:

```
player.loadVideo(videoId);
```

'OR'

First check that Video id is correct or not?

Comment: I changed that but still I didnt get a output.I checked the Video id that was absolutely correct.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications ... have you tried this sample demo by Youtube

Comment: try this sample code [youtube](https://github.com/TheFinestArtist/SimpleYouTubePlayer)